# Content Manager returns empty list

Tags: content-search, solr

I am on v8.2

Using SOLR as search index. I have the items indexed and can see them in the index. I kicked off index rebuild a few times.

However, `ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index").CreateSearchContext().GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()` returns nothing back. What could possibly the reason be?

I see the following in the search logs:

```
33576 12:10:47 INFO  Query - (_fullpath:(\/sitecore/content/home*) AND _template:(9865d2d89a6b4918863353525f8aad05))
33576 12:10:47 INFO  Serialized Query - ?q=(_fullpath:(\/sitecore/content/home*) AND _template:(9865d2d89a6b4918863353525f8aad05))&rows=2147483647&fl=*,score&fq=_language:(en)&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)
```

The item (both home and the item I am looking for) exists in the index, but like I mentioned nothing is returned back even if I don't apply any filters

Comment: There is a typo in your code - missing `n` in `index` word:  `"sitecore_web_idex"`

Comment: Fat fingers, marek. Typo in the question, not in the code :D

Comment: And what about the `9865d2d89a6b4918863353525f8aad05` template? Is it defined on the `SearchResultItem`? Is it `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes.SearchResultItem` or your custom one?

Comment: Can you try to use `.Where(item => item.Paths.Contains(homeItem.ID))` instead of `_fullpath`?

Comment: I doubt the changes will work. ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index").CreateSearchContext().GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>() returns nothing as well. No data i s being returned back is my issue.

Comment: Have you tried fiddle to see what is the request sent to Solr and what's coming back https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/017181 ?

Comment: If you paste 9865D2D8-9A6B-4918-8633-53525F8AAD05 in the search box in content editor, do you get back a template? Silly question, you are sure you published?

Comment: I do Chris :) Everything has been published many a time and reindexed as well. Put it this way. I can see documents in the index, but forget searching for a template - a simple ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index").CreateSe‌​archContext().GetQue‌​ryable<SearchResultI‌​tem>() call doesn't return anything back either

Comment: How do I check search queries in fiddler @MarekMusielak?

Comment: There is a link in my previous comment. If your application does any call to Solr, you will see it in fiddler. Together with the response from Solr.

Comment: I have followed the steps in the article @MarekMusielak still can't see the SOLR requests in the fiddler?

Comment: Have you tried the same with sitecore_master_index? This will help confirm if it's just related to the web DB or an issue with other indexes too.

Comment: @novicecoder check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647105/how-to-configure-fiddler-to-listen-to-localhost

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are seeing the content in your SOLR admin UI, but not in queries, one thing to check is the SOLR URL.

You've probably already checked this, but just in case, you need to validate that the URL you are loading for your SOLR Admin UI is the same SOLR instance you are connecting to from Sitecore.

Load `/sitecore/admin/ShowConfig.aspx` and check what the SOLR url is. I've seen a rogue patch file change the URL on me in the past to a network instance that doesn't have my data. The setting you are looking for is `ContentSearch.Solr.BaseServiceAddress`.

```
<setting name="ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress" value="http://localhost:8983/solr" />
```

Comment: Thanks Jay - verified again and the url is correct. I have wrapped the call around try catch anyway, so if the core/server can't be found then an error would be thrown/logged.